# PutObject with S3Object

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am copying an S3 object across different accounts.
While I can get the object using `S3Object s3object = sourceClient.getObject(bucket, key)`
how can I upload the same object?
putobject only accepts a file or an input stream.
Since I only need to copy, is there any way I can do it directly?

Answer (score 0):

You can extract the underlying S3ObjectInputStream, which inherits from InputStream:

```
S3ObjectInputStream inputStream = s3object.getObjectContent()
```

Answer (score 0):

When copying objects in S3, use `copyObject()`. It can copy without needing to download & upload the file. it also works in the same bucket or different buckets, and between regions and between AWS Accounts.

When copying between AWS Accounts, you will need to use a set of AWS credentials that has permission to Read from the Source bucket *and* Write to the Target bucket. This can be done in two ways:

**Option 1: Pull from Target Account**

- Use credentials from the Target Account
- Ensure those credentials have permission to write to the target bucket (in the same account)
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to the Source bucket that grants **s3:GetObject** permission to the credentials being used (eg the IAM User), such as:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": "s3:GetObject",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::TARGET-ACCOUNT-ID:user/USERNAME",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

This tells the Source bucket to allow the IAM User from the Target Account to `GetObject` from the bucket.

**Option 2: Push from Source Account**

- Use credentials from the Source Account
- Ensure those credentials have permission to read from the source bucket (in the same account)
- Add a **Bucket Policy** to the Target bucket that grants **s3:PutObject** permission to the credentials being used (eg the IAM User), such as:

```json
{
  "Version":"2012-10-17",
  "Statement":[
    {
      "Effect":"Allow",
      "Action": "s3:PutObject",
      "Principal": "arn:aws:iam::SOURCE-ACCOUNT-ID:user/USERNAME",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
  ]
}
```

- **Important:** When copying the object(s) using Option 2, be sure to specify `ACL='bucket-owner-full-control'`. This will make the Target Account the 'owner' of the object. If you do *not* do this, then the Target Account won't be able to manage/delete the object. It is only required when 'pushing' an object to a different account.

Comment: How do I do this in Java? I am getting the Read Access ARN and the source s3 uri via API Gateway into my lambda

Comment: In Java, use [copyObject()](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/AmazonS3Client.html#copyObject-com.amazonaws.services.s3.model.CopyObjectRequest-). Example: [CopyObject.java - AWS Code Sample](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/code-samples/latest/catalog/java-s3-src-main-java-aws-example-s3-CopyObject.java.html). Another example: [Amazon S3 copy object Java API](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41603258/174777)

Answer (score 0):

What is the use case here? Which SDK are you using?

There might be a "copy to" method available, like
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-java/latest/developer-guide/examples-s3-objects.html#copy-an-object, provided you have the permissions set up properly for cross-account access.

Otherwise it should be possible to get the object content as a stream (https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaSDK/latest/javadoc/com/amazonaws/services/s3/model/S3Object.html#getObjectContent--) and use that as the source.

Comment: How do I set up permissions? I am getting the source role ARN and S3 URI from API Gateway in to my lambda.

Comment: The documentation [here](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/cross-account-access-s3/) covers pretty much all scenarios..